# How do I configure the CometConnectionManagerValve for Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, comet, configure, atmosphere

I'm trying to get atmosphere running with tomcat 6.0. In the atmosphere whitepaper it is briefly mentioned that I have to "configure the CometConnectionManagerValve Valve" to have auto-detect remote client disconnection.
I have been googling on configure CometConnectionManagerValve. But nothing useful came up. Where do I configure this valve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this out a while ago. In the server.xml you can add the valve in the engine definition as follows:

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve"/>